# Take a screenshot of page using Chrome --headless + cookies/oauth token

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, headless, google-chrome-headless

I've found, that it's possible to take a page screenshot easily - https://superuser.com/questions/1410641/how-to-take-screenshots-of-a-list-of-urls - by calling:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --screenshot="C:\path\to\screenshot.png" http://example.com/
```

However it's starting new Chrome process, which results that I'm able to take a screenshots of simple pages, but what with pages, with authentication (like Oauth2)?
Can I somehow fore chrome, to use already existing "session" of browser, where I'm logged in to interested page, that I'm about to take a screenshot OR to pass oauth2 token or even cookie, somehow?